# Intent Service display image in ImageView

Tags: android, image, android-intent, service, show

I would like to display an online image in an image view with the use of Intent Service.

```
public class IntentServiceClass extends IntentService {
public IntentServiceClass() {
    super("IntentServiceClass");


}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent( Intent intent) {
    if (intent != null) {
        String URLImage = "https://tortoisesvn.net/assets/img/logo-256x256.png";
      Bitmap bmp = null;
        try{
            InputStream inputStream = new java.net.URL(URLImage).openStream();
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    }
```

}

I do not know if I am doing this wrong and how to continue. 
Can someone help me please?

Comment: Are you sure what you are asking?

Comment: Why using `IntentService` for such task use an image loader instead probably [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).

Comment: I am restricted to use Intent Service and cannot use any other methods.

Answer (score 0):

To display image into ImageView.
You can use `Glide` or `Picasso`. From an activity the code will like:

**Picasso**

```
  Picasso.get().load(url).resize(50, 50).centerCrop().into(imageView)
```

**Glide**

```
  Glide.with (context)
     .load ( "http://inthecheesefactory.com/uploads/source/glidepicasso/cover.jpg")
     .into (imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly access an `ImageView` (or any `View`) in your `Activity` from a `Service`, here is an article about how it can be done: [Ways to communicate between Activity and Service](https://medium.com/@ankit_aggarwal/ways-to-communicate-between-activity-and-service-6a8f07275297)

However, in your case, I'd recommend you **NOT USE** an `IntentService` for image loading. Consider using on the popular image loading libraries s.a. `Picasso`, `Glide` or `UniversalImageLoader`